# Hard Disk's Swap Partition Inactive and Ext4 Partition Not Automounting at Boot

Tags: partitioning, automount

At my wit's end with this one..  Relevant desktop specs:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Two encrypted RAID 0 SSD disks that boot into /
- One 1TB hard disk for data storage
- The md0 (i.e., RAID) device has only an Ext4 partition
- The hard disk has two partitions:  (i) 10 GB Swap and (ii) 990 GB Ext4

The 990 GB Ext4 partition is supposed to automount at `/home/pete/DataStore` upon startup, but despite all efforts thus far it does not.

Contents of the `/etc/fstab` file are:

```
UUID=c64572a8-9c34-45d6-9086-eaeb49bf9d03 /ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=e514c398-4915-41a5-8c9c-b5ae368c918a /home/pete/DataStore auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

Based on my reading, this looks sufficient for automounting, but obviously something is blowing up.  Moreover, the swap partition is always inactive at startup and has to be manually activated.

*However* if I use the Disks app to edit mount options and select `/dev/disk/by-uuid/[disk ID]` in the "Identify As" dropdown menu and keep the `/mnt/[disk ID]` mount point that automatically populates in the text box, then the Ext4 partition actually automounts!

I thought perhaps the differing directory privileges allowed automount at one location and not the other, so I changed ownership of "/home/pete/DataStore" from pete:pete to root:root.  Nothing.

Any ideas what I can try next to automount at /home/pete/DataStore?  Getting the swap partition to activate at startup would be icing on the cake.

Answer (score 2):

Your /etc/fstab entries are not correct

```
UUID=c64572a8-9c34-45d6-9086-eaeb49bf9d03 /ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=e514c398-4915-41a5-8c9c-b5ae368c918a /home/pete/DataStore auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

According to man page of /etc/fstab the correct format is

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>    
LABEL=t-home2   /home      ext4    defaults,auto_da_alloc      0 2
```

On the first line there should be space between / and ext4

```
UUID=c64572a8-9c34-45d6-9086-eaeb49bf9d03 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

On the second line there try to use ext4 instead of auto

```
UUID=e514c398-4915-41a5-8c9c-b5ae368c918a /home/pete/DataStore ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

There is no entry for your swap partition in /etc/fstab. First you have to find swap UUID with command sudo blkid

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda5: UUID="vvvvvvvv-wwww-xxxx-yyyy-zzzzzzzzzzzz" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="vvvvvvvv-wwww-xxxx-yyyy-zzzzzzzzzzzz" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="vvvvvvvv-wwww-xxxx-yyyy-zzzzzzzzzzzz" TYPE="ext4"
```

Add entry for swap in /etc/fstab

```
UUID=vvvvvvvv-wwww-xxxx-yyyy-zzzzzzzzzzzz none swap defaults 0 0
```

You can test your /etc/fstab settings on the fly with

```
sudo mount -a
```

Before using this command unmount partition you have changed in /etc/fstab

Comment: Adding the swap partition's entry into the fstab file worked (thanks).

Comment: However, changing the 990 GB partition's file system type from "auto" to "ext4" achieved nothing.  Moreover, something remains odd.  The Disks app claims the partition is mounted at /home/pete/DataStore at boot up, but such is not the case.  Running a simple ls command on the mount point in a terminal returns nothing.

Comment: Is there any error if you issue command `sudo mount -a` ?

Comment: No, there is no error when a 'sudo mount -a' command is issued.  The command actually does not mount the 990 GB partition when I first boot the computer.  I have to issue an explicit 'sudo mount /dev/sda2' command to mount the partition (i.e., sda2 is the 990 GB partition).  Really bizarre!

Comment: Is there correct uuid in /etc/fstab for /home/pete/DataStore ? Check with `blkid` command. As workaround you can put  /dev/sda2 instead of UUID=e514c398-4915-41a5-8c9c-b5ae368c918a but it is not recomended.

Comment: Yes, the UUID has been correct.  I tried an fstab version with /dev/sda2 instead of the UUID, and the behavior was the same.  Something about this partition...  I'm calling it a day on this one.  The issue seems highly specific to my situation and likely not of value to anyone else here.  Thanks for your time.